# ActionBarSherlock ShareActionProvider

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm having a problem in the implementation of ShareActionProvider ActionBarSherlock. Ja put all compenentes, but when I compile the code of NullPointException. Following error:

> 08-08 23:06:22.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2286): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   08-08 23:06:22.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2286): java.lang.ClassCastException: com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider cannot be cast to android.view.ActionProvider
>   08-08 23:06:22.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2286): at android.view.MenuInflater$MenuState.readItem(MenuInflater.java:359)
>   08-08 23:06:22.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2286): at android.view.MenuInflater.parseMenu(MenuInflater.java:145)
>   08-08 23:06:22.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2286): at android.view.MenuInflater.inflate(MenuInflater.java:95)
>   08-08 23:06:22.315: E/AndroidRuntime(2286): at br.ftsys.churrascalc.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:136)

My xml file is in res/menu/main:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:id="@+id/share" 
    android:orderInCategory="100" 
    android:title="@string/share" 
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:actionProviderClass="com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
```

Minha MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity{

private ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
. 
.
. 
. 
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {

    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    mShareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menu.findItem(R.id.share).getActionProvider();

    /** Getting the target intent */
    Intent intent = getDefaultShareIntent();

    /** Setting a share intent */
    if (intent != null)
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/** Returns a share intent */
private Intent getDefaultShareIntent() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Assunto");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Conteúdo!!!");
    return intent;
}
 }
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The `ShareActionProvider` you are using in code is not the correct provider.  Hence the class cast exception.  This is a result of importing the incorrect provider in your MainActivity class.  Just look for the line:

```
import android.widget.ShareActionProvider;
```

and replace with:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.widget.ShareActionProvider;
```

That's it